# Linux kernel thread created inside exception handler stalls

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am trying to create a Kthread within the body of the `__do_page_fault` exception handler.  This thread will do some work (print the pc of the user process that caused the exception, and trace it using ptrace).

Currently I am just printing the pc in a loop that does not return, but the system hangs after a while, as if the Kthread should return in order for the user process to continue execution.

This is the code of the Kthread:

```
  int th1( void * data ){
        struct task_struct *  tsk=  (struct task_struct*) data;
        int pid = tsk->pid;
        int id= current->pid;
        printk("thread %d is tracking  %d ",id, tsk->pid);
        while(true){
               mdelay(100000);
               printk("%d, %ud\n",id,task_pt_regs(tsk)->ARM_pc);
        }
    }
```

And this where it is created:

```
   if (likely(!(fault & (VM_FAULT_ERROR | VM_FAULT_BADMAP | VM_FAULT_BADACCESS)))){
     printk("the page fault was made by the procces id %d\n",tsk->pid);
     if(tsk->is_tracked == 0) {
        tsk->is_tracked=1 ;
        struct task_struct * child_debugger;
        void  * data = (void *) tsk;
        child_debugger = kthread_create(th1,data, "os2");  
        if(child_debugger) {
            wake_up_process(child_debugger);
         }else{
                printk("error\n");
        }
        printk("thread went out \n");
    }
   return 0 ;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Threads shouldn't be created in interrupt context (like in exception handlers).

For defer work from an exception handler you may use *pre-created* thread, or a workqueue.